# Add image in cart as product

Tags: php, opencart

Hi i have editor there user can customize business card.i am using Open Cart .Now i need when user click on order button than business card image add in to the cart.Is that possible.Any example have any one.

Comment: You do not need that. The resulting image should be saved as *product option* of type *file*, while the product is *just* **Business card** with the product option attached when inserted into the cart. This is the basic OpenCart behaviour and it is simpler (and cheaper) to accommodate to it...

Answer (score 1):

You want an extension like this:

http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension/info&extension_id=11874

or else one like this:

http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension/info&extension_id=12254

Both are premium extensions so you do have to pay for them... but if they do what you want and it saves you coding your own it is worth it...

Please rate this answer if it helped